# (Welsh probability chap3 problem5) What is the distribution of min of two independent geometric rv?

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent discrete random
>   variables, $X$ having the geometric distribution with parameter $p$ and $Y$ having the geometric distribution with parameter $r$. Show that $U= min\{X,Y\}$ has the geometric distribution with parameter $p+r-pr$

Solution: $P(U=u)= P(X\geq u, Y \geq u)=P(X \geq u)P(Y \geq u)=(\sum_{k\geq u}(1-p)^{k-1}p)(\sum_{s\geq u}(1-r)^{s-1}r)=$

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have $X \ge x$ attempts you need to have $x-1$ failures with probability $(1-p)^{x-1}$ so use something like $$P(U \ge u) =  P(X\geq u, Y \geq u)=P(X \geq u)P(Y \geq u) \\ =(1-p)^{u-1}(1-r)^{u-1} =\bigg((1-p)(1-r)\bigg)^{u-1} \\ = (1-(p+r-pr))^{u-1}$$ and you are done

Comment: OMG, when you put it like this, it really is simple. I thought we need to sum over $X=u, X=u+1...$ when calculating $P(X \geq u)$.